# Limiting controllers to specific request method

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, penetration-testing

From a security perspective. What is the worst that can happen when you have a controller that is wide open. What I mean by this is that you can call this controller using a post, get, put, delete, update, trace etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Most controller accepts a wide range of verbs.

Comment: What would be a good reason to not accept different verbs

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about a controller that's not decorated with `[Authorize]` attribute.

What is worst that can happen, depends on how you look at it. Suppose your controller has a get method, which exposes some privacy related information. That means this sensitive information is available for anyone who is on the internet.

Similarly if you have a `post` method to delete some information, anyone on the internet will be able to call the delete method.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific that method would be protected by forms authentication so the authorize attribute wouldn't be needed in this case. I'm thinking more of why would I need to decorate the controller with the http post or http get attribute. What's the harm and does mvc.net by default have any protections against doing other http protocols (not sure if that's the right wording )